# How to get a pop-up menu's owner window

Tags: windows, winapi, popupmenu

When opening a pop-up menu, one uses the function [`TrackPopupMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002), which takes as parameter "*a handle to the window that owns the menu*".

I'd like to know what's the owner window of any pop-up menu visible on the screen.

Is it possible to obtain a handle to such window, even if it belongs to another process?

I already tried the following WinAPI calls without success:

```
GetParent(menuHWND) ; //returns null
GetWindow(menuHWND, GW_OWNER) ; //returns null
GetAncestor(menuHWND, GA_ROOTOWNER) ; //returns menuHWND
```

---

**EDIT:**
I obtain a handle to the menu with the function `WindowFromPoint`

Comment: In your example, how did you get menuHWND? Are you not asking how to **get** menuHWND from a HMENU?

Comment: How are you identifying the menus?

Comment: How would you get the handle to that popup menu anyway?

Comment: @Michael, I edited the question 10 minutes ago mentioning that detail.

Comment: HMENUs are not “children windows” so you could get their parent with such a function. The value passed to TrackPopupMenu is merely a handle to send a message when the menu is dismissed, not a real “parent”.

Comment: @Michael, `parent` and `owner` are different concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetGUIThreadInfo` knows:

```
static DWORD CALLBACK MenuPeekerThread(LPVOID)
{
  Sleep(1500); // Wait for menu to show because this is just a silly example
  POINT pt = { 2, 2 };
  HWND hwndMenu = WindowFromPoint(pt);
  GUITHREADINFO gti = { sizeof(GUITHREADINFO), };
  DWORD tid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndMenu, NULL);
  if (tid && GetGUIThreadInfo(tid, &gti))
  {
    printf("owner is %p\n", gti.hwndMenuOwner);
  }
  return 0;
}

static void TestMenuThing(HWND hwnd)
{
  CloseHandle(CreateThread(NULL, 0, MenuPeekerThread, NULL, 0, NULL));
  HMENU hMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
  AppendMenu(hMenu, 0, 1, TEXT("Foo"));
  AppendMenu(hMenu, 0, 1, TEXT("Bar"));
  TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, NULL);
  DestroyMenu(hMenu);
}
```

`GetGUIThreadInfo` was added in Windows 2000, if you need to support anything older you need a [hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) and compare the HMENU parameter when the hook is called for the WM_INITMENU/WM_INITMENUPOPUP messages.

Comment: TPM_NONOTIFY+TPM_RETURNCMD would possibly break the suggested hook hack on older platforms.

Comment: I also thought of the possibility of using `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and then `EnumThreadWindows`. The first enumerated window should be the topmost window in the thread, which should also be the one owning the menu. Would this retrieve the same result as your code?

Comment: The order of windows enumerated by EnumThreadWindows is undocumented AFAIK. You at least might run into problems with always on top windows enumerated before the "active" window.